# How to redirect a user in Server component in Nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

I'm new to next js, and want to redirect a user server component without using `"use client"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get the question the question right, but a good way to redirect with next.js is setting up a middleware.

It's explained quite well in the [next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware).

If that's not what you're looking for, please specify your question a bit more

Comment: i try use `redirect` function but this function throw a error and make the window blank before redirect completed

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/redirect#redirect

Answer (score 5):

That's what you are looking for:

```js
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";


const Success: NextPage<{}> = async () => {
    redirect("/");

    return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen justify-center p-10">
    ServerComponent
    </main>
  );
};

export default Success;
```

Comment: Isn't `redirect` for server action only?

Comment: @Alexandre and server components

Answer (score 1):

I am also new in next js and i was facing same issue i want to register user and after successful registration i want to switch the page to login. i found a way that is redirect it is perfectly working in my server component. here is the code you can check how i redirect after successful registration.

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { getRegister } from "@/app/api/action/route";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const Register = () => {
  const handleSubmit = async (formData) => {
    "use server";
    const name = formData.get("name");
    const email = formData.get("email");
    const password = formData.get("password");

    const user = await getRegister({ name, email, password });
    if (user.ok) {
      redirect("/login");
    } else {
      throw new Error();
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid place-items-center h-screen">
        <div className="shadow-lg p-5 rounded-lg border-t-4 border-green-400 w-[500px]">
          <h1 className="text-xl font-bold my-4">Register</h1>

          <form action={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-3">
            <input
              name="name"
              id="name"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Full Name"
              className="p-2 rounded-md border border-gray-600"
            />
            <input
              name="email"
              id="email"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email"
              className="p-2 rounded-md border border-gray-600"
            />
            <input
              name="password"
              id="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              className="p-2 rounded-md border border-gray-600"
            />
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="bg-green-600 text-white font-bold cursor-pointer px-6 py-2"
            >
              Register
            </button>

            <Link className="text-sm mt-3 text-right" href={"/"}>
              Already have an account? <span className="underline">Login</span>
            </Link>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

This is my getRegister function or you can call an api

```
const { conn } = require("@/database/db");
const { default: User } = require("@/models/user");
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const { NextResponse } = require("next/server");

export const getRegister = async (formData) => {
  await mongoose.connect(conn);
  let user = await User.create(formData);
  return NextResponse.json({ user, success: true, status: 201 });
};
```

this is my approch if anyone have better and easy approch then please share with me thanks. although this code is working fine in my case